# Python key adding to url

Tags: javascript, python, cgi

I need to change key in url when user retrieves the link:

```
http://server.eu/word.py
```

to , for example:

```
http://server.eu/word.py?word=yellow
```

Could it be done by cgi library?

Also, may be now by url, but somehow in other way: I just need to send random word generated in python to the client.

Comment: `"http://server.eu/word.py?word={}".format("yellow")`?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look at the [Requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/install/#install) library, which is very pleasant to use. There are examples in the documentation on how to pass parameters:

http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls

In your case this would be something like:

```
payload = {'word': 'yellow'}
r = requests.get("http://server.eu/word.py", params=payload)
```

Comment: After importing requests (simply importing, without any code executing this library) I receive "Internal server error". Why could it be? Python server version?

Comment: Did you install the module? http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/install/#install . It's not part of the standard library.

Comment: It's not my server and I can't install their anything additionally. Is it possible to do in other way?